# i need to solve this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have installed `tensorflow` using link and installed it from cmd in windows 10.

But what is happening is when i run my program in `pycharm` it says the above error.

And i even installed `tensorflow` in my `pycharm` also still it is the same thing**

Error:

```
“ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'”
```

Comment: You need to update the project path in Pycharm -- the interpreter should be the one that you installed tensorflow with

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Python you are using vs the library installed in which location.

Check

`import sys`

`print(sys.path)`

It will be you `site-packages` folder. Usually the libraries will be there.

Check the above in PyCharm and Command Prompt.

Also, check for 
`pip show tensorflow` 
or
`pip show tensorflow-gpu`

Answer (score 0):

Check if package is installed in pycharm packages list:'

1. Open **Pycharm**
2. Go to **File** and then goto **Settings**
3. Go to **Project Interpreter**

Check if tensorFlow is present in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm by default runs in virtual environment so it does not by default adds global site packages so u need to install tensorflow in your venv
Go to Settings

> Go to Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter

There You will see list of packages available for ur venv
from here u can add or remove packages from venv

Comment: i am not running my pycharm program in vitual envr